# Create set of keys from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I wanted to create one set from a list whose entries are dictionaries. 
Any idea how to do this in short Python syntax?

From:

```
[{"a":45,"b":2,"c":"house"},{"a":36,"d":67,"e":"car"}]
```

To:

```
{"a","b","c","d","e"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = [ {"a":45, "b":2, "c":"house"}, {"a":36, "d":67, "e":"car"} ]
{ k for d in lst for k in d }
=> set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
```

Notice that I'm returning an unordered *set*, in the question's body you're printing a *list* with the keys, but the question's title states that a set of keys is required.

Comment: Assuming order doesn't matter (don't use a dictionary if it does), this works good to me.

Comment: Just arrived to the same result after experimentations:) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short syntax would be:

```
>>> dicts = [{"a":45,"b":2,"c":"house"},{"a":36,"d":67,"e":"car"}]
>>> set().union(*dicts)
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySet = set([])
for l in dictList:
    mySet = mySet.union(set(list(l)))
```